# How do I enable audio in a xrdp session

Tags: linux, audio, kde, pulse-audio, xrdp

I'm connecting to a remote device running `ubuntu 22.04` + `kde` + `xrdp`.

My understanding is that, to get audio forwarded through `rdp`, I need to install a `pulseaudio` plugin for `xrdp`. So far I've tried:

1. build & install [pulseaudio-module-xrdp](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/pulseaudio-module-xrdp) from source
2. use an installer script from [this blog](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15978)
3. kill and restart `pulseaudio`, logout and reboot
4. add the user to the `audio` group

None of these work. They did install some `.so`, but on the `Audio Volume` panel it always says *"No output or input devices found"*.

What should I do next? Do I need to modify any config to enable something? Or was I just fundamentally on the wrong way?